# Error check code wont deny strings with numbers or certain letters of the alphabet

Tags: java, error-handling

I have an error checker that makes sure the guess entered by the user 
a) Has a certain size (this works) 
b) Has no numbers (doesn't work) 
c) Doesn't use certain letters (doesn't work) 
Here is my code, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
System.out.println("Enter Code:");
  guess = input.nextLine();
  guess = guess.toUpperCase();
  while (guess.length() != v || guess.contains("[0-9]") || guess.contains("[ACDEFHIJKLMNQSTUVWXZ]")) { 
   System.out.println("Bad input! Try again");
   System.out.println("Use the form \"BGRY\" with your respective length of letters");
   guess = input.nextLine();
   guess = guess.toUpperCase();
  }
```

Comment: Read the JavaDoc on `contains()` - this looks for string _literals_. Instead you'd want to use `guess.matches(".*[0-9].*")` etc. However, as @prophet already stated you'll probably want to use a whitelist, i.e. use something like `guess.matches("[valid chars]{required length}")` (`{required length}` would require an exact length, if you want to use a _minimum_ length use `{required length,}` instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The java Sting.contains() method only checks if the string entered is a substring. To use a regex, try String.matches().

For example, to that the string only contains certain letters, use

```
while (guess.length() != v || !guess.matches("^[VALID CHARACTERS]*$")
{

}
```